# Contract creating another contract in a single source file

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, constructor

When deployed as a single source file is the address stored in variable `creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender)` within function `OwnedToken` referring to the address of the contract `TokenCreator` or the address of an external account?

```
contract OwnedToken {

TokenCreator creator;
address owner;
bytes32 name;

function OwnedToken(bytes32 _name) {
    owner = msg.sender;

    creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);
    name = _name;
}
function changeName(bytes32 newName) {

    if (msg.sender == creator) name = newName;
}
function transfer(address newOwner) {
    if (msg.sender != owner) return;

    if (creator.isTokenTransferOK(owner, newOwner))
        owner = newOwner;
}


contract TokenCreator {
    function createToken(bytes32 name)
       returns (OwnedToken tokenAddress)
    {

        return new OwnedToken(name);
    }
    function changeName(OwnedToken tokenAddress, bytes32 name) {

        tokenAddress.changeName(name);
    }
    function isTokenTransferOK(
        address currentOwner,
        address newOwner
    ) returns (bool ok) {
        address tokenAddress = msg.sender;
        return (sha3(newOwner) & 0xff) == (bytes20(tokenAddress) & 0xff);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);`

`creator` has the address of `msg.sender`.

`msg.sender` is the address of the account that creates `OwnedToken`.  There are 2 cases:

- an external account that creates `OwnedToken`

OR

- a contract, like `TokenCreator`, that creates an `OwnedToken` (via `new OwnedToken(...)`).

---

**When deployed as a single source file, only the last contract is instantiated on the blockchain**, an instance of TokenCreator which gets an address, call it `X`.

When a transaction is later sent to `X` invoking `createToken`, this is when OwnedToken is instantiated on the blockchain and `creator` in that OwnedToken will be `X`.

Note that `X` is different from the external account that is used to deploy the single source file.  And the external account invoking `createToken` can be the same or different as the one used to deploy the single source file.

Answer (score 1):

from the Solidity docs, here is an example of a contract that replicates another:

```
contract ReplicatorB {

    address creator;
    uint blockCreatedOn;

    function Replicator() 
    {
        creator = msg.sender;
       // next = new ReplicatorA();    // Replicator B can't instantiate A because it doesn't yet know about A
                         // At the time of this writing (Sept 2015), It's impossible to create cyclical relationships
                         // either with self-replicating contracts or A-B-A-B 
        blockCreatedOn = block.number;
    }

  function getBlockCreatedOn() constant returns (uint)
  {
    return blockCreatedOn;
  }

    /**********
     Standard kill() function to recover funds 
     **********/

    function kill()
    { 
        if (msg.sender == creator)
        {
            suicide(creator);  // kills this contract and sends remaining funds back to creator
        }
    }
}

contract ReplicatorA {

    address creator;
  address baddress;
  uint blockCreatedOn;

    function Replicator() 
    {
        creator = msg.sender;
        baddress = new ReplicatorB();    // This works just fine because A already knows about B
        blockCreatedOn = block.number;
    }

  function getBAddress() constant returns (address)
  {
    return baddress;
  }

  function getBlockCreatedOn() constant returns (uint)
  {
    return blockCreatedOn;
  }

    /**********
     Standard kill() function to recover funds 
     **********/

    function kill()
    { 
        if (msg.sender == creator)
        {
            suicide(creator);  // kills this contract and sends remaining funds back to creator
        }
    }
}
```

[github](https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/50_replicator.sol)